# wix heat tfs build

Tags: tfs, build, wix, robocopy, heat

Iam trying to run Heat.exe on TFS build - execution is fine althouth - heat gave me error message: 
'C:\PathToplace\Development\Install\WixInstaller\SKRwixInstaller\HarvestedFiles' did not contain any files or sub-directories and since empty directories are not being kept, there was nothing to harvest.
Clear message - before heat i do robocopy task - which should have copied all needed files for harvesting - works fine on local, but on TFS there is no file and any dir, just empty directory i made as well...found this a bit weird...output files are presented in place where they supposed to be - my output location is "as configured". Any idea?

Comment: My robocopy task has parameter file - loading robocopy multiple times - i just forgot to add it to source control...

Comment: so is it fixed? If you set it up as "as configured" it leaves all the files in their original directories (bin/debug, bin/release, etc) you need to copy them to the bin folder yourself (via robocopy is fine) so they they will be moved to the drop folder in the end.  So I would point my Heat.exe to the bin folder and try and build the MSI there.  This way it will be copied over to the drop folder as well.

Comment: Fixed! i'm running robocopy parametrized with external file - which include list of extension to copy - i forgot to commit it to the repository on server - then Heat couldn't find any files and therefore robocopy copied 0 files... :-) so place heat pointed to was nothing